# Picture for itemize/enumerate-marker

Tags: graphics, numbering, itemize

I posted a similar question here: [Stackexchange-Topic](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/366302/picture-as-numbering-for-section/366305?noredirect=1#comment903165_366305)

Now I'd like to use the same picture as a label (instead of bullets e.g.) in the itemize(/enumerate) environment.
Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, with `enumitem`: `\begin[itemize}[label=…]`

Comment: Please provide a minimal working example in your question.

Comment: See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/307717/how-to-create-very-customized-numbered-environments